# How to be collaborative & helpful yet concentrated on your goal

Tags: productivity, collaboration, covid-19, work-from-home, concentration

I like to help people and people show up to me for help many times. But many times in aggressive timelines on projects I am facing hard time to be both helpful & highly productive.

I like to resolve all dependencies first & finish work with focus. Now with everyone working from home, people can connect virtually over Skype, MS Teams, email, meetings. Improptu pings & chats are creating lots of distraction since it diverts whole attention from work I am engaged in. Can't be at do not disturb mode at all times since Teams & skype is only way to connect and I may miss something important. I ended up working late when no one is online or disturbing. Also WFH all the time due to COVID-19 is a factor in distraction since you can not isolate completely from home.

Can anyone suggest how you are managing focus effectively in work. Please share your experiences to enhance focus & productivity in Work From Home scenario.

Answer (score 3):

When working in the office, people who do not want to be disturbed because they need to focus on something just display a piece of paper with the message "Do not disturb".

Many communication solutions have this feature, to keep you connected, but not involved.

However, if being immersed in your work is "paramount", then you can just shut down these programs entirely. To not create worry for your colleagues, just send an e-mail telling them that you will not be available for XYZ time because of critical work needed to be done.

Comment: I partially agree with you. I mentioned that in question too, doing do don't disturb mostly is not possible & sometimes people don't take that in good faith. But informing them for availability before hand is nice touch.